# JLabel doesn't appear before sleep

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I am working on a simple Swing program that places one label on the frame, sleeps for one second, and then places another label on the frame as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class SubmitLabelManipulationTask {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Swing");
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("A Label");
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        label.setText("Hey! This is Different!");
      }
    }); 
  }
}
```

However, I cannot see the first label on the screen before the sleep. The screen is blank while sleeping. Afterwards, I see the original label for a split second and immediately afterwards the final label of "Hey! This is Different!" is on the screen. Why doesn't the original label appear on the JFrame?

Comment: You need to use a swing Timer

Comment: @AMB: no need for revalidate or repaint since he's not adding or removing components. OP, all you need is a Swing Timer in place of your sleep code, since the call to sleep is being done on the event thread and it is putting the entire GUI to sleep -- not what you want.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter thats what i want to say, ty

Comment: How long does it take to make the GUI w/out the sleep? For me, it takes about 1 second so your example 'works' but barely.

Answer (score 2):

It is much better and safer to use a Swing Timer in place of your sleep code, since the call to sleep risks being done on the event thread and this can put the entire GUI to sleep -- not what you want. You also want to take care to make sure that your GUI does in fact start on the Swing event thread. For example

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class SubmitLabelManipulationTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Swing");
            final JLabel label = new JLabel("A Label", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            frame.add(label);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(300, 100);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
                label.setText("Try this instead");
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `since the call to sleep is being done on the event thread` - The code in the main() method does not execute on the EDT. That is why when creating a GUI you need to wrap the code in an SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to place the code on the EDT. Maybe the sleep() method is automatically executed on the EDT, but I don't think so since there is no mention of this in the API.

Comment: "All you need is a Swing Timer" is not correct - the problem is that somehow `main` is being executed on the EDT. The given code works fine for me, maybe OP is using some IDE that executes the `main` on the EDT. Anyway the correct way is to use `invokeLater` as you did above to create and display the JFrame.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: good point. Still the code **should** in fact be called on the EDT since it creates and shows a Swing GUI. So best practices recommend what I am suggesting.

Comment: Same comment to @camickr.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter exactly what I meant by "Anyway the correct way is to use `invokeLater`..."!?!

Comment: I've tried using Timers before and the code above doesn't work. I've also tried putting the creation inside an invokeLater call as well. Strange. I'm running all of this code from the Terminal. Perhaps it's related to the way that my environment is set up, but I'm troubled by the inconsistency.

Comment: *"I've tried using Timers.."* **That** is the code you should be trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The code written by you is working perfectly fine without any issue on my machine..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class SubmitLabelManipulationTask {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Swing");
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("A Label");
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        label.setText("Hey! This is Different!");
      }
    }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: And what happens if the original poster **correctly** creates and displays his Swing GUI on the Swing event thread -- is your code still functioning as desired? In other words, what happens if all the code within the main method is wrapped in a Runnable and then queued on the Swing event thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`, as shown in the previous answer? Again, will your code work as expected/desired in this situation? And if not, why make recommendations that the original poster follow a faulty design?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels .. Agree with your point , i will not work as required.. i just tried the original code posted and it worked for me... Thanks for correcting me., removed my recommendation .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Matt's comment that the sleep is happening while the GUI is loading fixed the problem for me. Turns out that although the JFrame loads immediately, loading the other components takes around a second. So by the time the label is done correctly, the sleep is subsequently done and the label is switched almost immediately after. Changing the sleep (or the Timer) to over a second allows me to see the original label there for a little longer before it switches.

Comment: Still, your code is incorrect -- you should be creating and showing the GUI on the event thread and then using a Swing Timer as demonstrated in the first answer given to your question. Follow that recommendation and accept that answer as it is *most* correct of the bunch.