# Why does Thread.sleep() or TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep() delays execution of previous statements instead pausing from where sleep() is called

Tags: java, delay, sleep

I'm doing a simple thing, printing an error message, delaying the execution for 5 seconds and then calling another function, here's the code

```
public void saveAndDisplay() throws InterruptedException{
//printing error message
if(saveValuesToDatabase()){
        System.out.println("done");
        errorType = "Done, you will be redirected to MainProject";
        String message = "<html><body><font color='red'>"
            + errorType
            + "</font></body></html>";
        lblError.setText(message);
    } else {
        System.out.println("not done");
        errorType = "Some problem occured, try again";
        String message = "<html><body><font color='red'>"
            + errorType
            + "</font></body></html>";
        lblError.setText(message);
    }

 //delaying by 5 seconds
 //Thread.sleep(5000); or
 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

 //now calling another function
 doSomethingElse();
}
```

Instead of displaying error message - then delaying - then calling `doSomethingElse()`, execution is first delayed for 5 seconds then error message displayed and then `doSomethingElse()` called.
This is out of my understanding, because as I know statements get executed line by line in `java` then why `Thread.sleep(5000)` or `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)` gets executed first even if it not written there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing you. Is this real code? Can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I imagine that things are not being flushed until the method returns

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yes, this is the code, I've also posted the answer, and I think the code provided was as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Swing timer fires one or more action events after a specified delay, it is recommended to use `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` or `java.lang.Thread` and `java.util.Timer` when dealing with GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread.
More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Here's the code that worked for me

```
public void saveAndDisplay() throws InterruptedException{
//printing error message
if(saveValuesToDatabase()){
    ...
}
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

I think the problem was because the `Thread.sleep()` delays the current thread that is event-dispatch thread(EDT) which deals with GUI-related tasks as well, that is why the `lblError` was not being displayed until timer released the thread after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose your `lblError` is a `JLabel`.
In that case, the value of the label is set directly but control is not returned to the AWT thread until after the sleep. The label is therefore not updated on the screen.

Try using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`.

Your code may look like this:

```
// Compose message to put in label
// Must be 'final'
final String message = ...;

// Create runnable that sets the label
Runnable label_setter;
label_setter = new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    lblError.setText(message);
  }
};

// Set label within AWT thread and wait for it to finish
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(label_setter);

// Now we can wait
Timeunit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

...
```

Comment: Yes `lblError` is a `JLabel`. How to use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` in my scenario? Can you please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i'm wrong, but user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049730/jlabel-doesnt-appear-before-sleep) seems to have your problem and it was caused by the fact he was sleeping the entire GUI with sleep method, so that the gui updates occured only after the delay.
(I'm assuming you are using java swing)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, using `javax.swing.Timer` did the magic.